# Standalone STM32F030CC minimal configuration

Tags: stm32

I'm making a PCB with the STM32F030CC microcontroller and have been reading up on the minimal configuration in [the datasheet](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/a4/5d/0b/0e/87/c4/4d/71/DM00088500.pdf/files/DM00088500.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00088500.pdf). They don't include a minimal setup diagram, but I found some information on how to connect the power with filter capacitors.

[image]

I will be using all 6 UARTs, but nothing else. Do I need to have the ADC filter capacitors as I won't be using the ADC?

Is there anything essential for it to work that I have missed? I will be using the internal oscillator, so I won't need any external crystal.

Comment: Ther should be a hardware development starting guide on ST's website.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm making a PCB with the STM32F030CC microcontroller and have been reading up on the minimal configuration in the datasheet. They don't include a minimal setup diagram [...]

ST typically provide the minimal configuration information in a separate document for each of their MCU families, not in the datasheet. That document usually has "Getting started" as part of the title. For your MCU that document is "[AN4325 - Getting started with STM32F030xx and STM32F070xx series hardware development](http://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/dm00089834.pdf)".

> I will be using all 6 UARTs, [...] I will be using the internal oscillator so I won't need any external crystal.

I hope you've considered the HSI (internal oscillator) accuracy limits, temperature drift, and potential need for calibration.

> Do I need to have the ADC filter capacitors as I won't be using the ADC?

I believe you are referring to the capacitors across V<sub>DDA</sub> and V<sub>SSA</sub>, and yes, it still makes sense to do that because those pins provide power to other parts of the MCU too (e.g. the "Reset block" and the internal oscillators) not only the ADC.

Unless you are producing something that is *extremely* cost-sensitive, then you reduce your risk by following the ST guidelines. Note that their reference design (in the document linked above) lists a 1 uF V<sub>DDA</sub> capacitor in the "mandatory" section. Since the V<sub>DDA</sub> and V<sub>SSA</sub> pins are next to each other, it's really easy to added their recommended capacitor there.

> Is there anything essential for it to work that I have missed?

I haven't done a full design review, but one point is that your `BOOT0` pin has no pull‑up. So while it is tied to Gnd for booting from the main Flash then fine. However if you ever want `BOOT0` to be "high" (e.g. to use the built-in bootloader) then you should not assume a floating `BOOT0` pin will be treated as "high".

Comment: I have tested the internal oscillator, and it works fine for my use (i'm only running the UARTs at 250kbaud)

The Boot0 pin is supposed to have a internal pull-up according to the datasheet, so i think i will be fine. Edit: no it doesn't, i confused it with the reset pin

Comment: "I have tested the internal oscillator" - understood, but while they quote 1% accuracy at 25 degrees C (IIRC), I believe it could be up to 5% across the whole temperature range. If you are OK with that, or are sure to only use it at room temperature, then great!

Comment: i guess i'll have to bring out my hair dryer for a test ;) I should have room to add the traces for a external oscillator and not use it unless i need to

Comment: > I should have room to add the traces for a external oscillator. that would be my approach. when i design a board, I always lay down more than I would otherwise need so the board becomes more generic: if i needed a part, I can simply populate the board with it, as the traces are already there. having options is a good thing, especially if it doesn't cost you much.

Comment: @Pownyan - "add the traces for a external oscillator" - yes, I would do that; I would add a 3-pin footprint (centre pin gnd) where a resonator *or* xtal can be fitted, as well as footprints for the two xtal caps. "hair dryer for a test" - I would not do that, as that test doesn't give you the reassurance you might think. You don't know if *that* IC will show *max* freq deviation or not, so you might not provoke worst-case behaviour. Instead I would use a scope to check initial UART freq, then program BRR to cause worst-case (5%?) deviation; then test the overall system behaviour with ...

Comment: [cont'd] whatever devices are attached to your STM32F0. Also note that the receiver's clocks could be at the opposite end of the frequency tolerance i.e. the Tx could be fast and the Rx could be slow (or vice versa). That reduces the maximum UART freq deviation allowed at each end of the link. If the UART receivers are also STM32F0, then all of [STM32F0 Reference Manual](http://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00091010.pdf) section 23.4.5 "Tolerance of the USART receiver to clock deviation" applies. If the receiver is not STM32F0 then you need to adapt its formulas and advice.

Comment: A typical UART receiver is unlikely to cope with that worst-case 5% (or more - e.g. if the Tx is fast and Rx is slow) HSI frequency deviation from nominal, unless it is doing auto-baud rate detection often enough to follow changes in the Tx frequency. However that's all part of the overall system design, and not part of the original question. I just wanted to mention why I originally highlighted this point in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I have used STM32F030F on an adapter, absolutely nothing else and it worked like a charm.

However, what is minimal is quite subjective and application-specific. I would check the datasheet and see what's required from powering up the chip. Typically V<sub>dd</sub>/GND + decoupling, and then boot0/1 pins, reset, AVdd/AVREF if you want to do ADC, programming header and an LED - always invaluable.